# How Do I Wait for Prompt Before Writing to Stream?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, nsstream

I am trying to connect via TCP to a device and send commands.  The device displays a prompt ">" when it's ready for a command.  If I send commands too fast, the second one will be missed because the device is still processing the first command.   The easiest example is in the code below when connecting.  The "ATZ" command is processing, so the "ATSP0" command is missed.   What is the best way to add a buffer or loop to wait until the device send the next command in a queue?

```
import UIKit

class Connection: UITableViewController, NSStreamDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var messageView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ipAddress: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var port: UITextField!

    private var inputStream: NSInputStream!
    private var outputStream: NSOutputStream!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func connectServer(sender: UIButton) {
        let host : CFString = ipAddress.text!
        let port : UInt32 = UInt32(self.port.text!)!
        var readstream : Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
        var writestream : Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, &readstream, &writestream)

        inputStream = readstream!.takeRetainedValue()
        outputStream = writestream!.takeRetainedValue()

        self.inputStream.delegate = self
        self.outputStream.delegate = self

        inputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
        outputStream.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

        inputStream.open()
        outputStream.open()

        messageView.text = "\(messageView.text)Connected to " + ipAddress.text! + "\r"

        progSendMessage("ATZ")
        progSendMessage("ATSP0") //Prompt not ready and this command is lost
    }
    @IBAction func sendMessage(sender: UIButton) {
        let textToSend: String = self.sendText.text!
        if (textToSend != "")  {
            progSendMessage(textToSend)
        }
    }

    func progSendMessage(var message: String) {
        message += "\r"
        let data: NSData = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
        self.sendText.text = ""
    }

    func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent) {
        switch (eventCode){
        case NSStreamEvent.ErrorOccurred:
            print("ErrorOccurred")
            print(aStream.streamError?.description)
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.EndEncountered:
            print("EndEncountered")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.None:
            print("None")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.HasBytesAvailable:
            print("HasBytesAvaible")
            var buffer = [UInt8](count: 4096, repeatedValue: 0)
            if ( aStream == inputStream){

                while (inputStream.hasBytesAvailable){
                    let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
                    if(len > 0){
                        let output = NSString(bytes: &buffer, length: buffer.count, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                        if (output != ""){
                            print("server said: %@", output!)
                            messageView.text = messageView.text + (output?.description)! + "\r"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted:
            print("OpenCompleted")
            break
        case NSStreamEvent.HasSpaceAvailable:
            print("HasSpaceAvailable")
            break
        default:
            print("Default")
            break
        }
    }
}
```